# Full Text Search on one column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which I have a column that is of type nvarchar. The table can grow to have quite large number of entries. Search can be performed on this specific column so that for some entry on GUI implemented store procedure is finding all the matches. In that sp logic which is checking string matches is using LIKE %entered_phrase% on that particular column.
Now, since this can be rather inefficient, I wanted to use full text search for that particular column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_MyId ON MyTable(Id);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft_mycatalog AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable(MyColumn)
KEY INDEX ui_MyId 
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

However, when I perform:

```
select * FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(MyColumn, 'some_term')
```

no records are returned. What I am doing wrong?
(Same thing with LIKE, of course, works)

```
Id MyColumn
1  12345some_termwsdjf4sd
2  sdfsjdsfsdfsdfsdsome_term5dgd
3  4l00lko0dfsdfsome_term
```

So it should return all 3 entries. Having more columns in this table of course, but they are irrelevant now.

Comment: Could you clarify column name? ("MyColumn" vs "Value")

Comment: You created index by column MyColumn and make search by column Value

Comment: Ah, it's a misspell, Value is the name of MyColumn, so yes:
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(MyColumn, 'some_term')

Comment: give example data, where you expect to get result and it's empty

Comment: What happens if you use N'some_term' instead of 'some_term'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i know 'Contains' only returns if the words are matched with specific word that is delivered as search key - not partially matched. However you can force 'Contains' to return the result which have words started with specific search key like this example

```
select * FROM MyTable
WHERE CONTAINS(MyColumn, '"some*"')
```

It will give you the result which have words started with "some" in MyColumn.
Here is the Technet [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583(v=sql.110).aspx#Simple_Term)

My suggestion is to use 'like' instead of 'Contains'.

Comment: Yes, it is better to use LIKE or PATINDEX.
But turns out, larger number of scans which I found that stored procedure performs, is not due that particular line (with LIKE search), but rather because of some efficient join in it.